# Error: random is not a function solidity/web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am trying pull a random number generated from a function on my smart contract that uses the' block difficulty' and the 'block time stamp'.

The solidity code looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

 contract ApprovalContract {

  function random() external view returns (uint8){
  return uint8(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, 
  block.difficulty)))%251);
  } 
 ...
 }
```

The application code written in JS looks like this:

```
ApprovalContract.methods.random().call(
        function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
              console.log('error: ' + error);
            }
            else {
              console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            }
          });
```

All I need to do is log the randomly generated number to the console. Unfortunately, I keep seeing "Uncaught TypeError: ApprovalContract.methods.random is not a function"

Comment: I updated the ABI definition and random definitely shows up as a function in the ABI

Comment: Make the function public

Comment: The function is external, so you should be good in terms of accessibility. How are you initializating `ApprovalContract` in your javascript code?

Comment: @Henk var ApprovalContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,contractAddress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the () after methods.random. `random` isn't a function on `methods`, it's an object.

Comment: I don't understand though. How would I 'call' random if it shows up as an object?How do I access this data? I'm trying to implement rudimentary 2-factor authentication by generating a random number that I can call from the smart contract and then send it back to the smart contract in order to authenticate.

Comment: Random is a function in Solidity, but when web3.js generates the contract object for interacting with it, it creates random as an object. This is because it has multiple functions on it

Comment: so should I rename my function? I still don't see how I can access the data in random. Please help!!

Comment: Just change `ApprovalContract.methods.random().call` to `ApprovalContract.methods.random.call`. Random is an object on the methods object, not a function. You are calling an object as a function.

Comment: I did try that, I'm getting "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined". Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the fact that this needs to formatted as an asynchronous call ... I don't know anything about that >.<